# What was the rationale behind pinterest changing its "pin it" button to "save"?

Tags: usability, user-research, analytics

I recently noticed that the popular "pin it" button had been renamed to "save". Personally I did not like it as I thought "pin it" was more accurate for the purpose and also was more in sync with the brand and gave it uniqueness compared to the more common "save" button.

Would be good to know if anybody who was involved with the decision can spill some beans on why this change is being effected.

Answer (score 3):

According to Pinterest’s head of research, Gabe Trionfi:

> "*We are updating the ‘Pin’ button to say “Save” because we believe it
>   communicates that Pinterest is the best app for saving ideas you want
>   to do in your life... When you look at our internal data, you see that
>   people who are really engaged with Pinterest are more likely to
>   associate saving with the value of Pinterest. ‘Pin it’ doesn’t always
>   help people understand why Pinterest is valuable*".

http://www.forbes.com/sites/kathleenchaykowski/2016/06/02/pinterest-renames-pin-it-button-as-save/#7850b7205eb1